# Calculate expecting revenue in DataStudio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a table containing records for each transaction date and revenue. I would like to also calculate the Expected Monthly Revenue in the score board, and I am trying to use this equation:

```
sum(revenue) / (elapsed days / number of days in month)
```

However, I can't manage to get 1) elapsed days and 2) number of days in month.

For example, my data looks like

```
2019-10-1 $100
2019-10-2 $200
2019-10-3 $200
```

Then my expecting revenue for October should be

```
$500 / (3 / 31) = $5,167
```

I am not sure how to get 3 and 31 to the formula in calculated fields.
I also have a filter to range the dates, it is okay to generate non-sense result when the filter date range crosses different months.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get the "Day" part of that formula using the DAY function

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583526

You could then perhaps use the month function in a case statement to get the number of days each month. E.g.

```
CASE 
WHEN MONTH(date) IN ("January","March","May","July","August","October","December") THEN 31 
WHEN.....etc
```

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583310?hl=en&ref_topic=7583292

If it does work, it may only be for a single date though. I'd be interested to see if you can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

One way that it can be achieved is by using the new Date Time functions (released in the [17 Sep 2020 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467#sep-17-2020)).

The single [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below does the trick (where `Date` represents the respective Date field) and can be better understood by looking at the pseudocode in the question: `sum(revenue) / (elapsed days / number of days in month)`

- `sum(revenue)` = `SUM(Revenue)`
- `elapsed days` = `COUNT_DISTINCT(Date)`
- `number of days in month` = `AVG(DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME_ADD(DATETIME_TRUNC(Date, MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), DATETIME_TRUNC(Date, MONTH), DAY))`

```
SUM(Revenue) / (
    COUNT_DISTINCT(Date) / 
    AVG(DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME_ADD(DATETIME_TRUNC(Date, MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), DATETIME_TRUNC(Date, MONTH), DAY)))
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/ec63ae7a-4448-4efd-9f46-cb64709d4312) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]